# C# How to get the player from the list so I can print out their score

Tags: c#, list

I made a game where you first say how many players there are and then every player throws 3 darts and it loops until one player gets 301 points and now I want to get the player who got more than 301 points from the list of players and I want to get their score so I can print out their score and say that they won at the end of the game but I can't figure out how to do that. Thanks

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Game My_game = new Game();
        My_game.PlayGame();
    }
}

public class Game
{
    private List<Player> player_list = new List<Player>();
    private List<int> total_list = new List<int>();

    public void PlayGame()
    {
        Random random_number = new Random();
        int throw1;
        int throw2;
        int throw3;

        string more_players = "yes";

        while (more_players == "yes")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is the players name?: ");
            player_list.Add(new Player(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Are there more players?");
            more_players = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n Welcome to the dartgame! \n" +
                          "\n Game Rules: Each player throws 3 darts at a time." +
                          "\n Every throw can be worth 0-20 points." +
                          "\n Whoever gets 301 points first is the winner!");

        Console.WriteLine("\nPlayers:");

        foreach (var players in player_list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(players);
        }

        int total_points = 0;

        while (!player_list.Any(x => x.calculate_points() >= 301))
        {
            foreach (var players in player_list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n");
                Console.WriteLine("\n first throw for{0}!", players);
                Console.WriteLine("Press space to throw a dart!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                throw1 = random_number.Next(1, 20);
                Console.WriteLine("You got " + throw1 + " points!");
                Console.WriteLine("\n second throw for{0}!", players);
                Console.WriteLine("Press space to throw a dart!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                throw2 = random_number.Next(1, 20);
                Console.WriteLine("You got " + throw2 + " points!");
                Console.WriteLine("\n third throw for{0}!", players);
                Console.WriteLine("Press space to throw a dart!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                throw3 = random_number.Next(1, 20);
                Console.WriteLine("You got " + throw3 + " points!");
                total_points = throw1 + throw2 + throw3;
                Console.WriteLine("\nPoints for this round: " + total_points);
                total_list.Add(total_points);
                total_points = total_list.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
                players.Add_turn(throw1, throw2, throw3);
            }

            foreach (var players in player_list)
            {
                players.print_turns();
            }
        }
    }

}

class Player
{
    private string name;
    private List<Turns> turn_list = new List<Turns>();
    public Player(string _name)
    {
        name = _name;

    }

    public void Add_turn(int turn1, int turn2, int turn3)
    {
        turn_list.Add(new Turns(turn1, turn2, turn3));
    }

    public int calculate_points()
    {
        int total = 0;
        foreach (var turns in turn_list)
        {
            total = total + turns.Get_Score();
        }
        return total;
    }

    public void print_turns()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n----------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Points for {0}", name);
        foreach (var turns in turn_list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(turns);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n Total points: {0}", calculate_points());
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(" {0} ", name);
    }
}

class Turns
{
    private int turn1;
    private int turn2;
    private int turn3;

    public Turns(int _turn1, int _turn2, int _turn3)
    {
        turn1 = _turn1;
        turn2 = _turn2;
        turn3 = _turn3;
    }

    public int Get_Score()
    {
        int totalt;
        totalt = turn1 + turn2 + turn3;
        return totalt;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("\n throw 1: {0} \n throw 2: {1} \n throw 3: {2}", turn1, turn2, turn3);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Just a note that in normal darts, you're not allowed to go over the target score.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is how you *already* check if *any* players match the criteria:

```
player_list.Any(x => x.calculate_points() >= 301)
```

So as soon as one *does* match the criteria, you can get that single player:

```
player_list.Single(x => x.calculate_points() >= 301)
```

Or all matching players, if there's more than one:

```
player_list.Where(x => x.calculate_points() >= 301)
```

Or just the first matching player, if there's more than one but you only want one:

```
player_list.First(x => x.calculate_points() >= 301)
```

Or perhaps the player with the highest score (not accounting for a tie score):

```
player_list.OrderByDescending(x => x.calculate_points()).First();
```

Comment: Great answer!  Would like to see an answer not using Linq though.  This question seems to be coming from a new programmer, they would probably understand better not using Linq :)

Comment: @TheMiddleMan: Seems like an arbitrary request, given that the OP is already using LINQ.

Comment: thanks but how do I do if I want to print out the winner, that’s what I can’t figure out, like what is the syntax for getting that player and printing out the points again and saying that they won, I want to do that after the while loop but I don’t know how, sorry if I’m being unclear or if I’m missing something obvious, I’m fairly new to this hehe

Comment: @user8513203: The code you already have suggests that you are already familiar with the use of Console.WriteLine for printing to the screen.  Perhaps try that?  It's not really clear where you're stuck.